# Need help better understanding statistical terminology

Tags: statistics

True or False?

Hypotheses are always stated in terms of sample statistics

If the P-value for a statistical hypothesis test is as small or smaller than a pre specified significance level,  α, then one should retain the null hypothesis

Answer (score 0):

Both statements are false. Hypotheses are generally statements about the unknown state of nature....For example:  "The (true, unknown and likely unknowable) proportion of the population that prefers vanilla ice cream is less than 0.2"

The p value is the probability of observing what you observed if the null hypothesis is true. Thus, a small p value means that the observed value of the sample statistic would be very unlikely under the null hypothesis. This gives us reason to reject the null hypothesis.